CFO Estimation for CPM
I'm working on estimating and compensating the Carrier Frequency Offset (CFO) in Continuous Phase Modulation (CPM). In a noise-free scenario, I can accurately estimate and correct the CFO using the known preamble and the received preamble. However, when I add AWGN to the signal, the CFO estimation becomes inaccurate, leading to a significant increase in the Bit Error Rate (BER).
Could anyone recommend resources or methods for improving CFO estimation in CPM, especially in the presence of noise?
I'm using 2-ary CPM with a GMSK pulse of L=3.

I'd view CPM just as a special case of PSK here, and go with: well, any general carrier offset estimator for PSK should work in theory, unless the CPM pulse shape you're using contradicts that. What kind of CPM are you doing, specifically?

I am using 2-ary CPM, GMSK pulse with L=3.

What would universally work if an ininitial estimate is good enough to start reception is a decision feedback CFO estimator: you observe some phase sequence $\Phi[n]$, decide on some symbols $\hat s[n]$, from which you calculate that the phases $\hat\Phi[n]$ were sent (you essentially reconstruct the "clean" transmit sequence); then, $\Delta \Phi[n] = {\hat\Phi[n]}-{\Phi[n]}$ is the sequence of phase errors.
Your noise leads to, on average, zero phase error. Therefore, you can fit a linear function to your $\Delta \Phi[n]$, whose slope would be CFO divided by symbol rate. Remember that frequency is just the derivative of phase over time!
You can use the $\hat s$ that you get through hard decision before you feed the symbols into your channel decoder, or you can use the symbols coming out of your channel decoder. The latter sounds smarter – they should have fewer errors after error correction – but depends on BER at the beginning of recovery still being good enough for the decoder to work.
